# Proguard removing ORMLite annotation in just one field

Tags: android, ormlite, android-proguard

I have this class

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = HelloWorld.TABLE_NAME)
public class HelloWorld {

public static final  String TABLE_NAME = "hello_world";

public static final  String COL_ID     = "id";

public static final  String COL_TEXT   = "text";

private static final String COL_SUBTEXT = "subtext";

@DatabaseField(columnName = COL_ID, generatedId = true)
private int    mId;

@DatabaseField(columnName = COL_TEXT, uniqueCombo = true)
private String mText;

@DatabaseField(columnName = COL_SUBTEXT, uniqueCombo = true)
private String mSubText;

public HelloWorld() {
}

public HelloWorld(String text, String subText) {
    mText = language;
    mSubText = subText;
}

public String getText() {
    return mText;
}
}
```

This is what happens: When I run my Android app in debug mode everything is fine. When I do it in release conf, basically proguard is taking out the @DatabaseField annotation from the id field. This is my query:

```
final List<HelloWorld> helloworld = mHelloWorldDao.queryBuilder()
                                                                        .orderBy(HelloWorld.COL_ID, true)
                                                                        .where()
                                                                        .eq(HelloWorld.COL_TEXT, "hello")
                                                                        .query();
```

This is the exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown column name 'id' in table hello_world
```

I tried to enable proguard in debug and try to debug ORMLite. Basically, when it's time to create the DAO, ORMLite looks for annotated fields. In this case, it's able to get the text and subtext fields, but when it looks for annotations in the id fields it doesn't find any annotation.

This is my proguard conf:

```
    # ORMLite
-keep class com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers class com.j256.** { *; }
-keep enum com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers enum com.j256.** { *; }
-keep interface com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers interface com.j256.** { *; }
-keep class com.almworks.**
-keepclassmembers class com.almworks.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.j256.**
-dontwarn com.almworks.**
-keepattributes *Annotation*
```

Am I missing something? Is there any strange rule involved?

EDIT:

If I add getters and setters for the ID field, everything is working. Event if they are not used. I don't like this solution. But anyway, there should be a rule below it.

Comment: Clear your app data and try again.

Comment: Have you found any solution yet? Facing the same problem here.

Comment: Not yet. If you look at the EDIT section in my question, I had to add getters and setters to make it work. Even if they're not used. Really weird